# swift How to view progress of downloadTask in several ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

I have two viewControllers VCList(CollectionView with items) VCDetails by selecting item from VCList it opens VCDetails, on VCDetails I have button download that starts downloading huge file according selected item with showing its progress, by dismissing VCDetails I want to show progress on VCDetails, and on entering again on that VCDetails if its is still downloading I want to show continued progress of downloading.
Please any suggestions on how to achieve this?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have any code so far? Even some high level "pseudo code". I'm asking because this sounds like something you should tightly tie - including the design of your code (reusable components) to multiple threading.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a loosely coupled notification. I would suggest having your download process broadcast `Notification` messages to the main thread at modest intervals (every few seconds). Then have the current view controller subscribe to those notifications and use them to update a download progress indicator.

Better yet, create a reusable download progress indicator that takes a download ID and listens for progress updates. Have your download manager return a unique download ID, and pass that to the view controllers that need to display progress. Have the view controllers install the download ID into their reusable download indicators views.

Comment: As an example I want to achieve something like in Netflix iOS app there is to view controllers a film details view controller which has download button and downloads view controller which is in embedded in navigation view controller so when you tap download button in film details view controller you can track progress in it also you will see progress of download in downloads view controller, sorry for my English )

Comment: Ok, I gave you a suggestion on how to do it.